# Is there any effective repellent against deer flies (Lipoptena cervi)?

Tags: bugs

Is there any effective repellent against deer flies (*Lipoptena cervi*)?
It should be safe for humans as well as dogs.

All related information I could find is about a different deer fly (*Chrysops*).

Answer (score 6):

It looks like lemon eucalyptus extract has some effect,

> It is concluded that the use of a repellent based on **lemon eucalyptus extract** (tested in 2004-2005) will protect humans from Deer ked bites, but just on those **parts of the skin where the repellent has been applied**. The smell of lemon eucalyptus is not enough to keep those blood suckers away.

[The Deer ked Lipoptena cervi (L.) - a blood sucker expanding its range](https://eurekamag.com/research/020/236/020236419.php)

There is also a paywalled study on the bugs,

> Using human targets, we explored the cues the deer ked uses for host selection. We studied which part of the host body deer keds target and if body colour and temperature affect their choice. In our experiments, deer keds landed more on dark and red clothing than on white clothing. Moreover, deer keds mostly attacked the upper body parts and preferred the back side of the body over the front side. Finally, deer keds preferred the warmest areas of the host.

[Experiments on the ectoparasitic deer ked that often attacks humans; preferences for body parts, colour and temperature](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-entomological-research/article/experiments-on-the-ectoparasitic-deer-ked-that-often-attacks-humans-preferences-for-body-parts-colour-and-temperature/368C7399621DF2B0DB03D7FA49B195A5)

Finally, given that you are in Finland, do note that there are repellents specific to deer flies like this [one](https://scandinavianoutdoor.com/autan/gear/small-accessories/hirvikarpasstop/) which I found by Googling "lipoptena cervi repellent"

Answer (score 0):

Cannot speak to your specific species, but I have found that any form of grease:  lard, margarine, butter, engine oil, transmission oil, is effective against at least horse flies, black flies, sand flies and whatever deer fly infests Canada's north.

They will continue to do touch and go landings, but won't bite.

Don't think this will work for your dog wholesale, but it may help for inside ears,and top of nose, and around eyes.